# Placing an Picture in ImageView selected from Gallery

Tags: java, android

I want to select an image from gallery and place that selected image in the `ImageView`.  I have also an `Intent` that will take picture through camera and place it in `ImageView` and it is working well. But, gallery `Intent` is only opening the chooser and then select the image, but it is not getting placed in the `ImageView`

In Log this error is coming up

> E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0

Open Gallery Method

```
 private void openGallery() {
    tvGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening Gallery, Please wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;
            Intent galleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
            galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(galleryIntent,PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
            Log.e("Status:", "Photopicker canceled");


        }
    });
}
```

onActivityResult

```
  protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    /*camera preview*/
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        previewView.setImageBitmap(bp);
    }
    /*gallery preview*/
   else if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
            cursor.close();
            previewView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);
            previewView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
        }

    }
}
```

**LOG ERROR**

```
09-08 15:40:02.355 30860-30860/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:03.836 30860-30860/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/Status:: Photopicker canceled
09-08 15:40:07.460 30860-30860/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
09-08 15:40:21.754 30860-30860/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/OpenGLRenderer: SFEffectCache:clear(), mSize = 0
09-08 15:40:32.885 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.885 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.885 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.media.session.MediaController', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.895 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.widget.Toolbar', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.905 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.ActivityManager$TaskDescription', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.915 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.915 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.945 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.SharedElementCallback', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.965 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.app.assist.AssistContent', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.975 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.SearchEvent', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:32.995 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.os.PersistableBundle', referenced from method bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld.Activity.activity.utils.PostNewIssue.access$super
09-08 15:40:33.225 32246-32246/bluecoppertech.com.taskmeld E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
```

Comment: what's the wrong with the question, that you down-voted the question?

Comment: What you showing the log error is incorrect! can you post full log error.

Comment: `android.os.PersistableBundle`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to place an image into `ImageView` from Gallery

`private int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;`

```
private void openGallery() {
        tvGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent();
                // Show only images, no videos or anything else
                intent.setType("image/*");
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);


            }
        });
    }
```

> OnActivityResult

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        /*camera preview*/

        if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {


            if (requestCode == 0) {
                Bitmap bp = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                previewView.setImageBitmap(bp);
            }
        /*gallery preview*/
            else {

                Uri uri = data.getData();

                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
                    Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));


                    ImageView previewView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);
                    previewView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is the working solution of choosing a picture from library or capturing one from camera and using it in a imageview.

Source : SO

```
//functions to select image from the device
    private void selectImage() {
        final CharSequence[] items = {"Take Photo","Choose from Library", "Cancel" };
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(signature_new.this);
        builder.setTitle("Add Photo!");
        builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Library")) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(
                            Intent.ACTION_PICK,
                            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    intent.setType("image/*");
                    startActivityForResult(
                            Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),
                            SELECT_FILE);
                } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            }
        });
        builder.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA) {
                Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
                ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bytes);

                File destination = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),
                        System.currentTimeMillis() + ".jpg");

                FileOutputStream fo;
                try {
                    destination.createNewFile();
                    fo = new FileOutputStream(destination);
                    fo.write(bytes.toByteArray());
                    fo.close();
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                imageF.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(thumbnail));

            } else if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {
                Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
                try {

                    Bitmap bm=decodeUri(selectedImageUri);
                    imageViewF.setImage(ImageSource.bitmap(bm));
                    //uploadbm=bm;
                    //dialog_dimension();
                }
                catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the intent to open gallery

```
Intent Gallery_intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                    startActivityForResult(Gallery_intent, constants.RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

and this is on activity result

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
     if (requestCode == constants.RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
 File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
        BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.RGB_565;
        b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(getRealPathFromURI(data.getData()), options);
        int bmpHeight = b.getHeight();
        int bmpWidth = b.getWidth();
        if (bmpHeight > 1500) {
            bmpHeight = bmpHeight / 4;
            bmpWidth = bmpWidth / 4;
        }
        Bitmap out = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, bmpWidth, bmpHeight, false);

        File file = new File(dir, "resize.png");
        FileOutputStream fOut;
        try {
            fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
            fOut.flush();
            fOut.close();
            b.recycle();
            out.recycle();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }

         ImageView.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file));
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Correcting your code... your conditions are quite wrong in onActivityResult

```
private void openGallery() {
    tvGallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Opening Gallery, Please wait..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            // Show only images, no videos or anything else
           intent.setType("image/*");
           intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
          // Always show the chooser (if there are multiple options available)
          startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);


        }
    });
}
```

Your OnActivityResult

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri uri = data.getData();

        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(getContentResolver(), uri);
            // Log.d(TAG, String.valueOf(bitmap));


            previewView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);
            previewView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));


            ImageView previewView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgPostIssue);
            previewView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```